# apt-get build-dep is unable to find a source package

Tags: apt, compiling

I have already followed [this guide](https://www.assembla.com/spaces/slipstream/wiki/Disabling_GTK's_middle_mouse_button_functionality) to disable middle mouse button paste on my Ubuntu 12.04.

Works like a charm.

Now I am trying to achieve the same on my Linux Mint 17. When I try to

```
sudo apt-get build-dep libgtk2.0-0
```

it gives me the following output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Picking 'gtk+2.0' as source package instead of 'libgtk2.0-0'
E: Unable to find a source package for gtk+2.0
```

For me it looks like apt-get is somehow "resolving" `'libgtk2.0-0'` to `'gtk+2.0'`, but then does not find any package named like that.

EDIT: 
although I am now able to compile the program (see my answer), I still do not know what  `Picking 'gtk+2.0' as source package instead of 'libgtk2.0-0'` is supposed to mean. Any insight on this would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Have you enabled the relevant `deb-src` repository in your /etc/apt/sources.list?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

As others have already noted, make sure that for every `deb …` entry in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/*`, you have a matching `deb-src …` entry. The rest of the line must be identical.

The `deb` entry is for binary packages (i.e. ready to install), the `deb-src` is for source packages (i.e. ready to compile). The reason why the two kinds of packages are separated is that they are managed very differently: binary packages have a dependency tracking mechanism and a currently-installed list, whereas source packages are only tracked so that they can be downloaded conveniently. 
Note that when discussing package repositories, the word *source* means two unrelated things: a source as in a location to download packages from, and a source package as opposed to a binary package.

`libgtk2.0-0` is the name of a binary package. It is built from a source package called `gtk+2.0`. The reason source and binary package names don't always match is that building a source package can produce multiple binary packages; for example, `gtk+2.0` is the source for 14 packages as it is split into two libraries (`libgtk2.0`, `libgail`), corresponding packages to build programs using these libraries (`…-dev`), documentation for developers (`…-doc`), companion programs (`libgtk2.0-bin`), etc.

You can see the name of the source package corresponding to a binary package by checking the `Source: …` line in the output of `dpkg -s BINARY_PACKAGE_NAME` (if the package is installed) or `apt-cache show BINARY_PACKAGE_NAME`.

You can list the binary packages produced by a source package with `aptitude search '?source-package(^SOURCE_PACKAGE_NAME$)`.

The command `apt-get source` downloads a source package. If you give it an argument which isn't a known source package, it looks it up in the database of installable binary packages and tries to download the corresponding source package.

The command `apt-get build-dep` follows the same approach to deduce the name of a source package, then queries the source package database to obtain a list of binary packages (the list in the `Build-Dep:` field), and installs those binary packages.

The Software Sources GUI has a checkbox “enable repositories with source code” for official repositories, make sure that it's ticked. If you add third-party repositories manually, make sure that you add both `deb-src` and `deb` lines.

Answer (score 9):

**CLI method**

```
sudo sed -Ei 's/^# deb-src /deb-src /' /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt-get update
```

Tested on the Ubuntu 18.04 Docker image. After this change, I can successful do for example:

```
sudo apt-get build-dep hello
```

and before the change it failed with the error:

```
E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list
```

See also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/496549/error-you-must-put-some-source-uris-in-your-sources-list/857433#857433

**`software-properties-gtk` option "Source code"**

From the GUI, you can run:

```
software-properties-gtk
```

then under the "Ubuntu Software" tab click "Source code":

[image]

This has added some `deb-src` lines under `/etc/apt/sources.list`, and now I can do `sudo apt-get build-dep <package>`.

Tested on Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04.

Answer (score 6):

Thanks to @steeldriver, I figured out what to do.

Just had to add the following ling to my `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
deb-src ftp://ftp.de.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib
```

deb-src repositories contain sources packages (as opposed to binary, ready-to-install packages) needed for compiling.

Edit: After Adding this, you must execute `sudo apt-get update`